# Por que usar translateZ ou translate3D nas animações feitas com CSS? Animações aceleradas por hardware em CSS?

Tags: css3, desempenho, navegador-de-internet, ux, css-animations

Hoje em dia é bem comum ver mesmo nos sites mais simples efeitos de animação feitos com CSS, tanto com `transition` quanto com `@keyframes` e algo que tem me chamado a atenção é que várias dessas animações utilizam artifícios para forçar uma aceleração por hardware setanto valores como:

```
.anima {
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   -o-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Também é comum ver `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` ou até `transform: rotateZ(360deg)` para de alguma forma usar o `eixo Z`, mesmo que sem valor (0), para habilitar a aceleração de hardware usando a GPU para processar a animação. Mas sabendo que o Chrome por exemplo é um famigerado consumidor de memória surgiram algumas dúvidas...

**Minhas dúvidas estão ligadas a UX e Performance:**

- Para que serve esse tipo de artifício e como ele afeta as animações? Isso traz alguma vantagem pro usuário?
- Animar algo que seria um 2D com propriedades 3D não aumentaria o consumo de bateria e memória do sistema por exemplo? Qual o impacto disso em dispositivos mobile que normalmente tem o hardware mais limitado?
- Se eu tiver várias animações na página eu devo usar isso em todas elas ou existe alguma boa prática com relação a isso?

Comment: Cara, tem a ver com _GPULayer_ e _composite_. Vou deixar [estes](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/) [artigos](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/) para referência, se eu conseguir mais tempo e inteligência eu monto uma resposta :P

Comment: @fernandosavio lerei obrigado pela dica!